# Page Life Cycle - Control has no value on Page_Init(), Page_load() is too late

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, jquery-select2

I have a select2.js multi select.  The selected values in this multi select will cause other controls to be created after a postback.  Select2.js isn't designed to retain its contents through a postback, so I added a bit of JQuery to make it work:

```
                    <select id="selectParameters" multiple="true" runat="server" clientidmode ="Static" style="width:100%;" class="textBox;">
                    </select>
                    <asp:hiddenField ID="hdnParameters" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />

        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready( function () {
                    $("#selectParameters").select2({
                        placeholder: "Select parameter(s)"
                    });

                    if ($("#hdnParameters").val != "") {
                        // This is not a postback - Move all currently selected items into the hidden selection
                        $("#hdnParameters").val($("#selectParameters").val());
                    } else {
                        // This is a postback - Use the hidden selection to populate the currently selected items
                        $("#selectParameters").select2("val", $("#hdnParameters").val());
                    }

                    $("#selectParameters").on("select2:select", function (e) {
                        // Selection was updated - Move all currently selected items into the hidden selection
                        $("#hdnParameters").val($("#selectParameters").val());
                    });

                    $("#selectParameters").on("select2:unselect", function (e) {
                        // Selection was updated - Move all currently selected items into the hidden selection
                        $("#hdnParameters").val($("#selectParameters").val());
                    });

                    $("#btnAllParameters").click(function(){
                        // Select all
                        $("#selectParameters > option").prop("selected", "selected");
                        $("#selectParameters").trigger("change");
                        $("#hdnParameters").val($("#selectParameters").val());
                        return false;
                    });

                    $("#btnNoParameters").click(function () {
                        // De-select all
                        $("#selectParameters > option").prop("selected", "");
                        $("#selectParameters").trigger("change");
                        $("#hdnParameters").val($("#selectParameters").val());
                        return false;
                    });



                });

            </script>
```

This works fine for retaining the values of the .select2 through the postback, and the select2 gets repopulated properly during page_load.

Elsewhere in the code, I'm using findControl() to access the values contained in the dynamically created controls (Which are created based upon the contents of the select2 control).  In order to use findControl(), the controls need to be generated during page_init.

```
Private Sub page_init() Handles Me.Init
    If IsPostBack Then
        Dim parameterSelection = hdnParameters.Value
        ' Add some controls to the page based upon the contents of parameterSelection
     End If
End Sub
```

In the code above, parameterSelection = "" if I run this code during page_init.

If I run the identical code during page_load, parameterSelection gets the value that I expect and everything runs fine (Except I can't use FindControl() on the dynamically created controls since they weren't created during page_init)

I'm looking for a solution such that I can access the values contained in the dynamically created controls after the postback.

- Presently I load the select2 during page_load, however the dynamically created controls won't be accessible via FindControl() as they weren't created during page_init
- I can't create the dynamic controls based upon the values of the select2 during page_init, as the hiddenfield and the select2 don't appear to have values at that time

Comment: No, server-side will always execute first. I'd suggest storing the selections in an `<asp:Hiddenfield>`, that way you can get/use the selected elements in the code-behind without having to wait for the javascript.

Comment: Just tried, hdnParameters doesn't have a value during page_init.

Comment: Is it an `<asp:Hiddenfield>` with `runat="server"`? I suggested a hiddenfield because it's an ASP.Net control that retains its value during postback.

Comment: Yep, here's the declaration:

`<asp:hiddenField ID="hdnParameters" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />`

During page_init hdnParameters.value = ""
As far as I can see I'm not resetting its value anywhere.

Comment: If `hdnParameters` is a hiddenfield, you need to use `.val`, not `.text`.

Comment: Was swapping between a label and a hiddenfield in order to view the data.    Good call, I've fixed the JQuery to work with a hiddenfield.  Still not sure why the value isn't being retained on postback.

Comment: Please update the code in your question with your update. The value wouldn't be retained on postback because the code-behind is unaware of the hiddenfield's text, it's completely reliant on the value. By setting the hiddenfield's *value*, I'd expect it to be maintained on postback.

Comment: LoadViewState occurs after Page_Init.  
During Page_Init the hidden control exists, but it doesn't yet have a value.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!  To retrieve the value of the hidden field during page_init I used:

```
parameterSelection = Request.Form("ctl00$contentPlaceholder$hdnParameters").ToString.Split(",").ToList
```

For some reason, despite using clientIDMode="Static", the control has a non-static identifier when requesting it from the form (Are static identifiers assigned later on in the page life cycle?)

This worked out - Found the proper identifier while browsing through Request.Form in debug mode.

Thanks for your suggestions Santi